# For Loop, the program will not follow my for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, jgrasp

For Loop, I am trying to understand why the loop will not run. Does anyone have any loop examples I can see?
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Conversion 
           for (t = ttt; t >= ttt + 36; t +=5) //counter = counter + 5 
           {    
           }

System.out.println ("t \t ttt");

System.out.println(j + "\t\t " + i);

//Show result
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C++? Why the C++ tag?

Comment: C++ Tag removed -- please take care with your question tags as posting the wrong tag can attract the wrong attention to your question.

Comment: And your for loop looks to do nothing, will never loop, it's a "futile" loop -- what do you expect that it should do?

Comment: The stop condition in your cycle `i >= i + 36;` is always `false`, so that the loop will finish immediately

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop has no body, and therefore it isn't doing what you want it to do. If you want to print out the conversion of inches to centimeters for every 6 inches between `i` and `i+36` your `for` loop should be

```
System.out.println("Inches\tCentimeters");
for(double j = i; j <= i + 36; j += 6) {
  System.out.printf("%f\t%f\n", j, inchesToCM(j));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless it overflows, `i` will never be greater or equal to `i+36`. You should use a different variable for your loop:

```
for (double j = i; j >= i + 36; j+=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `i = i` is redundant. If you already defined the variables, you can leave it empty.
Second, you are always asking if i is greater or equal to itself plus 36, in which is ALWAYS false. Try to pre calculate it.

```java
double limit = i + 36;
for (; i >= limit ; i +=6) //counter = counter + 6
{ }
```

And by the way, be careful with iterating with double variables, you can have wrong outputs in Java, due to the way it treats the decimals. You could have an extra loop.

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day :)